# Crop, Resize and Cut all in one command - FFMPEG

Tags: ffmpeg, lossless-compression

I am trying to do three tasks with FFMPEG

1. Crop a video without losing quality
2. Resize (upscale) the cropped video with good quality
3. Cut specific part of a the upscaled vided without losing quality

**Here are the command line I use:**

to crop: video og.mp4 to video og1.mp4

`ffmpeg -i og.mp4 -vf "crop=1330:615:22:120" -c:v libx264 -crf 1 -preset veryslow -c:a copy og1.mp4`

to resize: video og1.mp4 (converted above) to video og2.mp4

`ffmpeg -i og1.mp4 -vf scale=1920:-1 -c:v libx264 -crf 1 -preset veryslow -c:a copy og2.mp4`

to cut: video og2.mp4 (converted above) to og3.mp4

`ffmpeg -i og2.mp4 -ss 00:00:08.190 -t 00:00:11.680 -c:v libx264 -crf 1 -preset veryslow -c:a copy og3.mp4`

**I want to achieve highest quality of 1920 width video (irrespective of height and size of the file)**

*Is there a way to get the above tasks in one command or shorter time with best quality?*

*Also advice if there is a better command or parameters to be used.*

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can combine all commands by using a single filterchain, and adding the trim as well

```
ffmpeg -ss 8.190 -t 11.680 -i og.mp4 -vf "crop=1330:615:22:120,scale=1920:-2" -c:v libx264 -crf 1 -c:a copy og1.mp4
```

With crf `1`, a slow preset is unnecessary.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. One thing I observed. You had changed the scale from `1920:-1` to `1920:-2`. Can you please explain reason for the change?

Comment: The most compatible pixel format for H264 is yuv4:2:0 which requires even dimensions.

Comment: sorry but i did not understand. By even dimensions, do yuo mean it will make a square video 1920x1920? Actually, I wanted to maintain aspect ratio and make it 1920x1080 and that is why i added `1920:-1` by reading somewhere on google. Can you please shed some light on it on what should I use to maintain aspect ratio

Comment: Even, as in `1920x1080` not `1920x1081`

Comment: great! Thank you so much for the explanation and a desired solution

Comment: Two queries: 1. It gives me error if the "to time" is greater than 60 seconds. I wrote it as `-t 08.11.680` what is the correct syntax? I changed the way it was in my question `-t 00:08:11.680` which worked but I got a warning `Warning: data is not aligned! This can lead to a speedloss` How to avoid this?

Comment: *which worked but I got a warning* --> the original syntax is correct and it has no relation to this warning which is concerning pixel format conversion. You can ignore it.

Comment: Thank you... God bless !